# Json parsing strategy in Android

Tags: android, json, performance, parsing

I have a large json file (~3.5 MB), with (~140) complex objects, and the max depth in the object graph is about 4-5. I use Gson to parse it, but it's really slow. I've tried some way to parse it (like mixed parsing or using stream to parse), but I couldn't increase performance.

I checked Memory Analizer, it kill memory (70-80%), if I only parse the base Id of the objects. While parsing there are 400-500k object in memory (mostly string and char).

Would be parsing more efficient if the object graph wouldn't be so deep? Do you have a good idea how could be better? I tried other libs too (like Jackson), but performance wasn't better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some good performance boost by using Jackson - you should not load whole json into memory but use createJsonParser(Reader r). If it does not work for you then either try spliting data and use separate threads - it makes sense if CPU is not fully loaded by single threaded version. Otherwise try using JNI json parsing implementation.

Comment: Thanks marcin_j, parsing only parts of whole Json and with Jackson lib my problem is solved. 

Result: Parsing time was ~3 min before, and now only 7 sec.
        Memory usage is much more better: only 3-4 MB instead if 20MB.